# How to use globalize.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, globalize

I want to format numbers using globalize.js. I've added required libraries, but do I need anything else?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>test</title>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cldrjs/0.4.5/cldr.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cldrjs/0.4.5/cldr/event.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cldrjs/0.4.5/cldr/supplemental.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cldrjs/0.4.5/cldr/unresolved.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/globalize/1.1.1/globalize.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/globalize/1.1.1/globalize/plural.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/globalize/1.1.1/globalize/number.js"></script>
    <script>
        function text() {
            var val = $("#txt").val();
            Globalize.load({
                "supplemental": {
                    "parentLocales": {
                        "parentLocale": {
                            "en": "en-US",
                            "ja": "ja-JP"
                        }
                    },
                    "likelySubtags": {
                        "de": "de",
                        "en": "en",
                        "fr": "fr",
                        "ja": "ja"
                    }
                }
            });
            Globalize.locale("en");
            var formatter;
            formatter = Globalize.numberFormatter();
            console.log(formatter(3.141592));
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="fm">
        <input type="text" id="txt" onclick="text();" />
    </form>  
</body>
</html>
```

I get the following message in the browser console:

> cldr.js:339 Uncaught Error: E_MISSING_BUNDLE: {"locale":"en"}

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to load the right cldr bundler.

I dont know much about the library but I found this that might help you.

https://github.com/rxaviers/cldrjs#how-to-get-cldr-json-data

I made a simple node app that you can run by typing in

```
    node app.js
```

It will console.log what you wanted but I don't know what further implementation you want from there. Look at the code to see what dependencies you were missing. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you, Bruce Wong's 
I also do not know how can I describe the source code the page I saw, but which files are needed.

Comment: Having the scripts in your local directory makes it difficult for me to help. I'd have to go download everything individually. If you could upload your directory to github that i could clone. I can try to help more.

Comment: The source code was rewritten to those using a CDN. What can be seen anything?

Comment: you're working with a huge data set. Basically you haven't loaded the data in your script yet so it can't find the missing bundle. Are you planning to run this as an html page or are you using something like node.js to make it into a web application?

Comment: It was being examined whether it could be used to make web application. But there was no information Node.js needs, so it isn't used.

Comment: I looked at the source code and it is missing external datasets. The easiest way I could think of creating this application is using a nodejs backend to retrieve the data and then process it. 

You have to use Cldr.load((require("cldr-data/main/en-US/ca-gregorian")); or any other dataset before you can create an instance of Cldr.

Globalize.locale("en") is trying to return an instance of Cldr which hasn't been initialized using .load() so that is why you get that error. 

Running this on node in the backend you can use require to get the datasets you need.

Comment: Cldr.load ... I wrote a while has been output the following error.
index.html: 36 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined.
I have not used the node.js. So I give up because I think that it is a difficult problem to me. Thank you until now.

Comment: Expected value If you have a running a sample application that you made me has been output.
However, since the mechanism is not known at all to study the node.js. Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes, require is part of the CommonJS library that node.js uses. The require statements basically loaded the data that was needed for the Globalize.locale() function to work. 

require is not part of the standard browser libraries so you won't be able to run it in the browser. Only in Node.

Sorry I can't be anymore help.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the application on node.

https://github.com/CelesteComet/stackoverflow